# USB Dongle ZTE MF667 Not Showing Up in Network Menu in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: networking, 20.04, usb-modem, mobile-broadband, zte

I have problems connecting to mobile internet using ZTE MF667 dongle on an old DELL Inspiron N5040. The networks menu isn't showing any mobile broadband connection; neither is it showing up in the network settings.

*lsusb* recognizes it, returning:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 19d2:2000 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM MF627/MF628/MF628+/MF636+ HSDPA/HSUPA
```

The same dongle works like a charm on a Lenovo ThinkPad T440 with the same distro.
Another dongle I have, a Huawei one, works on the Inspiron, showing up in the menu and connecting.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You of course have tired different USB ports on the machine?

Comment: Thank you @David, yes, I've tried all three ports the Dell has.